# How checking value from DB table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want create a simple checking value from database. Here is my code:

```
def check_user_name(name, email)
db_name = Customers.find_by_name(name).to_s
 db_email = Customers.find_by_email(email).to_s
if name == db_name && email == db_email  
  return 'yes'
 else 
  return 'no'   
end
end
```

But I have allways 'no' variant....why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are calling `to_s` on your `Customers` model and not actually getting the name. The two fetch lines you have should be:

```
Customers.find_by_name(name).name.to_s # to_s probably not necessary if you know this field is a string
Customers.find_by_email(email).email
```

But, you're making two separate requests to the database. I don't know what the purpose of this is (as you could be selecting two different Customers) but you could do:

```
if Customers.where(name: name, email: email).exists?
  "yes"
else
  "no"
end
```

Since you are, however, selecting by name and email - I would highly recommend that you make sure those fields are indexed because large tables with those requests will bog the server and make that route rather slow (I would actually recommend that you pursue other routes that are more viable, but I wanted to mention this).

Comment: Hello. I little change your code:
`if Customers.where(:name => name, :email => email)`
now, i allways have 'yes' :)

Comment: It shoud be `if Customers.where(:name => name, :email => email).exists?`

Comment: @JohnOggy What is used is hash syntax as of Ruby 1.9 and what you're using is the older hash syntax. Either is perfectly acceptable and should be used depending on your preference. But `{name: "A Name"}` in 1.9 is the equivalent of `{:name => "A Name"}`.

Comment: @Baldrick Thanks, I should have looked that up - I assumed it would operate similar to the `create`/`save` methods that can be used in an if. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you give Customers.find_by_name(name), you will not get name of a customer. Actually it will return activerecord object, so from this object you need to get the name and email of a customer, like below,

```
name = Customers.find_by_name(name).name
email = Customers.find_by_email(email).email
```

Now you will get the exact name and email of matched data from DB.